# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi página web con html descargue archivos .bat haciendo un solo click?

Tags: html

Buen día, he logrado hacer que en mi página web con html descargue archivos pdf y archivos de imagen pero necesito hacer que también descargue archivos (.bat)

La imagen, el pdf y el .bat lo tengo en la misma carpeta, este es el código:

```
<section></br> <a href="../BusinessIntelillence/content/DashBoard_PowerBI.bat" download>Go to</a></br></section>
    <section></br> <a href="../BusinessIntelillence/content/bg4.jpg" download>Download image</a></br></section>
    <section></br> <a href="../BusinessIntelillence/content/Los7H.pdf" download = "Libro_De_7">Download book</a></br></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

tengo una solucion, pero requiere que los alojes en sitios como github, si los guardas alli, puedes copiar el link de descarga de cada archivo y colocarlo en el codigo, al hacer click lo deberia de descargar inmediatamente, usando el atributo download(html5)
seria algo asi:

```
<a href="insertar link de descarga" download="nombredelarchivo">
Descargar Archivo
</a>
```

la idea de alojarlos en github es que se vuelven mucho mas accesibles que teniendolos en local, o en un servidor, ademas si tuvieses que editarlos, no habria que editar nada de la web siempre que el link sea el mismo

Comment: Convendría le exliques el por que la necesidad de alojarlos donde mencionas

Comment: cierto, edito para añadirlo